# How to test state in abstract class in phpunit

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, code-coverage

I have a problem with test some condition which is in public method of abstract class, but the value of variable in this condition is set in protected method in one of the concrete classes. How I can test this branch (behind the condition).

```
abstract class AbstractClass 
{
    protected ?string $data = null;

    protected function runBeforeSomething(): void
    {       
        // Somewhere in some concrete class
        // 
        // $this->data = 'string data';                 
    }

    public function doSomething(): void
    {
        $this->runBeforeSomething();
        if ($this->data !== null) {
            //do magic...
            //@TODO How to test this branch?
        }
    }
}
```

Have you got any idea to solve this? Of course some rewrites of code are possible and welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Write a class extending your abstract class, just for the test. In that class, implement `runBeforeSomething()` and set the data there.